# Angular Pikaday multiple date format

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, datepicker, pikaday

I am using [Pikaday](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday.git#master) date picker plugin in my angular JS app.

Is it possible to have different format for view and different format while submitting?

For ex: 01 Jan 2014 (Display)
01/01/2014 (while submitting the form)

I know i can apply a filter while posting the content. However, since the date picker is been used in many places i have to do it at all the places separately. It will be great if the plugin updates my ng-model with a certain format but displays it differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this by using angularjs directive (formatters and parsers).
For example using moment.js:

```
app.directive('fdate', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(elem, $scope, attrs, ngModel){
            ngModel.$formatters.push(function(val)
            {
                return moment(val).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
            });
            ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){
                return moment(val, "DD/MM/YYYY").valueOf();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

and in your html:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="obj.yourdate" fdate>
```

i found this fiddle as an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wNBAn/